# Pre-interpret Django site at deployment time

Tags: python, django, fabric

I deploy Django apps using a fabric script that checks out a copy of my project and when everything is in place the source is symlinked and the web server is reloaded (guessing this is a typical approach).

My concern is that the first time the site gets hit after deployment all the python scripts need to be re-interpreted.

I have some bright ideas about how I might force the code to get processed before any clients hit it but I'm looking for any high-level strategies people might use to accomplish this.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

-Mike

Comment: Is this initial load time bothering you?  Or are you pre-optimizing something that -- actually -- has no measurable effect on your site?  What performance problems do you **actually** have and are you sure they're not internet, database or filesystem related?

Comment: @S.Lott I've noticed in my dev environment (which reloads the code each time it's changed) that the first time I hit the newly changed code the request takes substantially longer. I'm assuming end users could have the same problem on the live server when new code is deployed. Am I wasting my time trying to pre-compile for this reason or should I worry? Thanks.

Comment: "I'm assuming end users could have the same problem".  Why assume that?  Measure.  It's clearly not true, BTW.  But you should measure instead of simply assume.   "Am I wasting my time trying to pre-compile".  Completely.  Also, you have a terrible measurement bias.  One load (**one, 1**) out of the countless number of requests being processed before the next software update is *insignificant*.  Don't dwell on things that happen **once**.  Dwell on things that happen every single request.  Database performance, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python -m compileall /path/to/django/site
```

Will precompile any .py files under the directory recursively.

How are you running django? If you're using WSGI the interpreter or interpreters are already running and would have already compiled a lot of your django site. What is being dynamically loaded?

Comment: Cool thanks. Yeah using WSGI w/ Apache. So when I reload Apache much of the python is getting interpreted? I was under the impression that nothing got processed until the first page was requested.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only way mod_wsgi runs is with a configurable number of python interpreters (>=1) which may or not be threaded. When apache starts these wsgi "worker" processes your django site is loaded.

Comment: Since they all share a common set of files, the very first time an interpreter starts, .PYC files are built.  The rest can then read the .PYC files, saving a tiny bit of time.  They do, however, have to read the .PYC files, which does take some time.  And, they have to search for template files.  And open a database.  The compilation time is tiny compared to the real overheads.

Comment: Sure, then if there haven't been requests to the website then the WSGI processes could be swapped out. And when requests are frequent you can get better read performance from templates due to the OS disk cache. There are all sorts of reasons why you might see poorer or better performance over time.

Comment: @MattH: Agreed. And, these effects (swapping, file system, database) far, far outweigh any benefit from attempting to prevent or avoid "all the python scripts need to be re-interpreted"  (Whatever that means.)

Comment: I precompile all of the files for my django projects because it saves me a bunch of selinux warnings. WSGI seems to run under the context of apache which doesn't have rights to write the .pyc files when my project is stored under a home directory with the rest of an application, even if WSGI is running under owning UID.

Comment: @MattH: We use distutils and a writable egg cache.

Comment: @S.Lott If my statement "all the python scripts need to be re-interpreted" makes no sense please help me (and possibly others) understand what really happens.

Comment: @Mike Bannister: Python is generally interpreted.  The usual Python configuration means that all Python code is always interpreted at all times.  **At All Times**.  The "reinterpreted" can't be a problem because it's the normal execution mode.  What did **you** mean when **you** used this word?